# Change UISegmentControl height with respect to label height

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, xib, uisegmentedcontrol

I have one `UISegmentControl` in my app. I have added all the required constraints and set its height constraint as `>= 40`. Control has 3 segments. Problem is I am getting the segment title data from server and it can be of any length. When segment title exceeds one line the text gets truncated.

I solved this problem by adding below code:-

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISegmentedControl class], nil] setNumberOfLines:0];
```

It works fine when title length is of 2 lines. The real problem starts when title length takes more than 2 lines and than again text is getting truncated, ideally `UISegmentControl` should increase its height to accommodate longer tile like UILabel does by checking its content compression property. I tried playing with contentCompression resistance property by changing value of priority but in vain. `UISegmentControl` doesn't resize automatically to accommodate larger text. Any idea how can I achieve the desired behaviour using auto layout.

Comment: I think we are supposed to use `setTitleTextAttributes(_ attributes: [AnyHashable : Any]?, for state: UIControlState)` for `UISegmentControl` instead of the method currently used

Comment: I used text Attributes by setting `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` to `NSMutableParagraphStyle` but still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I only speak Swift so I hope this helps.

There are a number of things you need to do to dynamically adjust the height of your segmented control.

1.Make an extension to UILable like so:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

    extension UILabel{
        var defaultNumberOfLines: Int{
            get{return self.numberOfLines}
            set{self.numberOfLines = newValue}
        }

        var defaultFont: UIFont{
            get {return self.font}
            set{self.font = newValue}
        }
    }
```

2.Calculate the bounding rectangle that is going to contain your string. The height of this rectangle will dictate the height of your segmented control. You can calculate the bounding rect of a string using instances of NSString or NSAttributedString but not String. I calculated the bounding rect in the "getHeightForSegControl(withString:withWidth:)" method.

3.You also have to remember to use the same font as the UILabel when calculating the bounding rect for the string or else your text is going to be truncated because of apparent discrepancies...

4.Set your frames in the method viewWillLayoutSubviews(). This is important because whenever you set a new text to a segment you need to call the setNeedsLayout() of your super view to calculate the resulting bounding text and the corresponding size of your segmented control.

In the code below if you change the value of instance member "text" to a string of any length the segmented control will update its height accordingly:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    var text = "This is a text that is supposed to dynamically change the height of an instance of UISegmentedControl"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpSegmentedControl()
        UILabel.appearance().defaultNumberOfLines = 0
        UILabel.appearance().defaultFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

        segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 100, y: view.bounds.size.height / 2 - (getHeightForSegControl(withString: text, withLabelWidth: 100) / 2), width: 200, height: getHeightForSegControl(withString: text, withLabelWidth: 100))
    }

    func setUpSegmentedControl(){
        segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: [text, "Oranges"])
        view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    }

    func getHeightForSegControl(withString string: String, withLabelWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let nsString: NSString = string as NSString
        let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingRectSize = nsString.boundingRect(with: size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UILabel.appearance().defaultFont], context: nil).size

        print(ceil(boundingRectSize.height))
        return ceil(boundingRectSize.height)
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

P.S. this is assuming you want a fixed width. If you also want a dynamic width... that is a different story.

Comment: Yes may be u are right I also achieved the same effect by looping through subviews of `UISegemenControl` and than checking the height of `UILabel` to adjust the height of UISegmentControl. As I mentioned in the comment I wanted to do it through `AutoLayout` so above code is not an option for me. I still think using intrinsic size we can achieve the desired result.